# C# [XML2Array] Error parsing the XML string

Tags: c#, xmlhttprequest

i received an Error when i am posting a XML file via `HttpWebRequest`. I would like to show the response as an label.

My Code:

```
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https:xxxxxxxxxxxx");
            byte[] bytes;
            var file = Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments + "\\myRequest.xml";
            bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(file);
            request.Headers.ToString();
            request.ContentType = "application/xml; encoding='utf-8'";
            request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
            request.Method = "POST";
            Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            requestStream.Close();
            HttpWebResponse response;
            response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                string responseStr = new StreamReader(responseStream).ReadToEnd();
                label13.Text =  responseStr;
            }
```

My Response in label13.Text = The supplied data could not be imported in the stated format -[XML2Array] Error parsing the XML String

Comment: Where are you parsing the XML?  The error is in the data you are sending to the server and not what is received in the response.  HTTP has special characters that you cannot send (see wiki : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references).  Looks like you are sending unacceptable characters to the server.  Then the server is not returning xml instead an error message.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I created a html file where i can upload my XML File and POST it to the same API. I receive a correct response but when i am doing the same thing wiht my code above i received the Message 'The supplied data could not be imported in the stated input format'. I also tried the process via Postman and i also receive the error message.

Comment: The server may not accept an xml request.  Not all servers are the same.